# How to read in scala a long number that was packed in python

Tags: python, scala, character-encoding, stream

My scala program receives (through tcp) a long number that was packed in python:

Python sends Long values in that way:

```
connection.send(struct.pack("!L", 2052))
```

Scala receives by reading stream:

```
...
val dataInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"))

val buf = new Array[Char](4)
dataInputStream.read(buf,0,4)
val realLongNum = bufArrayToLongNumber(buf)
```

My buf array contains number from which I can calculate the required Long number by myself:

```
def bufArrayToLongNumber(buf:Array[Char]):Long =  
  (buf(0)*256*256*256 + buf(1)*256*256 + buf(2)*256 + buf(3))
```

I hoped to find an existing function that do this calculation

Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigInt` actually has a constructor which takes `Array[Byte]` (so you'd have to do convertion from `Array[Char]`):

```
val bi = BigInt(buf.map(_.toByte))
```

That would also handle the situation when your number doesn't fit Long. You could also get `Long` by just calling `bi.longValue`.

If you're certain your number will always fit to `Long`, I'm not sure that it's a better solution than yours.

Answer (score 3):

This might work.

```
val realLongNum = buf.foldLeft(0L){case (a,b) => (a<<4) + b.toLong}
```